# How can I write to an fp16 surface?

Tags: cuda, gpu, textures, gpgpu

I have a 4 channel texture / surface that are allocated with the following descriptors:

```
cudaChannelFormatDesc cuda_map_desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 32, 32, 32, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMallocArray(&cuMapLeftArray, &cuda_map_desc, map_width, map_height));
cudaResourceDesc map_resource_desc{};
map_resource_desc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
map_resource_desc.res.array.array = cuMapLeftArray;
cudaTextureDesc map_texture_desc{};
map_texture_desc.normalizedCoords = false;
map_texture_desc.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
map_texture_desc.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
map_texture_desc.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
map_texture_desc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
CUDA_CHECK(cudaCreateTextureObject(&MapLeftTexObject, &map_resource_desc, &map_texture_desc, NULL));
CUDA_CHECK(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&cuMapLeftSurf, &map_resource_desc));
```

Here is how I write to it in a cuda kernel:

```
float4 addr_val = make_float4(pixel_left.x, pixel_left.y, pixel_right.x, pixel_right.y);
surf2Dwrite<float4>(addr_val, g_mapL, ix * sizeof(addr_val), iy);
```

Here is how I read the data in a different kernel:

```
float4 coords = tex2D<float4>(map_left, map_x, map_y); // returns image coords (not normalized)
```

I wish to try utilizing fp16 support in cuda and convert the code to use `half` instead of float.

How can I convert the provided code samples to utilize half / fp16? Is this even possible / efficient?

I tried simply changing the channel size from 32 to 16 but I could not find good docs / examples on how to read write to this kind of objects.

Comment: [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/does-cuda-support-16-bit-surfaces/111446) and [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#bit-floating-point-textures) may be of interest.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks. but these docs are very unclear. I can allocate an fp16 texture, but I have no idea how to convert my kernels to read / write this kind of texture. In particular, there is no simple float4 -> half4 conversion. there is no half4 type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is adapted from the surface write/texture read [cuda sample code](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/0_Introduction/simpleSurfaceWrite) ("simpleSurfaceWrite") and also taking note of the [relevant programming guide section,](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#bit-floating-point-textures) excerpting:

> The 16-bit floating-point or half format supported by CUDA arrays is the same as the IEEE 754-2008 binary2 format.

> CUDA C++ does not support a matching data type, but provides intrinsic functions to convert to and from the 32-bit floating-point format via the unsigned short type...

> 16-bit floating-point components are promoted to 32 bit float during texture fetching before any filtering is performed.

> A channel description for the 16-bit floating-point format can be created by calling one of the cudaCreateChannelDescHalf*() functions.

There are at least 2 ways to tackle this:

1. We could use purely 16-bit traffic: writing `ushort4` quantities in the surface write kernel and reading `ushort4` quantities in the texture read kernel.  [Conversion](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC.html#group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC) from `ushort` to `half` (or `float`) is demonstrated in the host code of the first example below; it can be used similarly in device code as needed.  For this we need a channel descriptor specifying `ushort4`.
2. We could use a mostly 16-bit definition, but take advantage of the note above: "16-bit floating-point components are promoted to 32 bit float during texture fetching".  Using this methodology, our general setup isn't much different, our surface write kernel is unchanged, but we will specify a "half4" channel descriptor (effectively switching from integer to "floating point mode" in the texture unit) and our texture read kernel will now read `float4` quantities instead of `ushort4`.

Examples of both follow:

```
# cat t65.cu

/*
 * demonstrate "half4" texture/surface using ushort4 texture fetch
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cuda_fp16.h>
#include <iostream>
#define checkCudaErrors(x) {cudaError_t err=x; if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cout << "CUDA Error at line: " << __LINE__ << " " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;}
using mt = ushort4;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Kernels
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Write to a cuArray (texture data source) using surface writes
//! @param gIData input data in global memory
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
__global__ void surfaceWriteKernel(mt *gIData, int width, int height,
                                   cudaSurfaceObject_t outputSurface) {
  // calculate surface coordinates
  unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  // read from global memory and write to cuarray (via surface reference)
  surf2Dwrite(gIData[y * width + x], outputSurface, x * sizeof(mt), y);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! read data using texture lookups
//! @param gOData  output data in global memory
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
__global__ void texReadKernel(mt *gOData, int width, int height,
                                cudaTextureObject_t tex) {
  unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  float u = x;
  float v = y;

  // read from texture and write to global memory
  gOData[y * width + x] = tex2D<mt>(tex, u, v);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  // Get number of SMs on this GPU
  cudaDeviceProp deviceProps;
  const int devID = 0;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProps, devID));
  std::cout << "CUDA device [" << deviceProps.name << "] has " << deviceProps.multiProcessorCount << " Multi-Processors, SM " << deviceProps.major << "." << deviceProps.minor << std::endl;

  // create data
  unsigned int width = 256, height=256;
  mt *hData = (mt *)malloc(width*height*sizeof(mt));

  unsigned int size = width * height * sizeof(mt);
  // populate
  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      unsigned short x = __half_as_ushort(__float2half(row));
      unsigned short y = __half_as_ushort(__float2half(1.0f));
      unsigned short z = __half_as_ushort(__float2half(col));
      unsigned short w = __half_as_ushort(__float2half(2.0f));
      ushort4 val = {x, y, z, w};
      hData[row*width+col] = val;}

  // Allocate device memory for result
  mt *dData = NULL;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dData, size));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dData, hData, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  // Allocate array and copy image data
  cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<ushort4>();
  cudaArray *cuArray;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocArray(&cuArray, &channelDesc, width, height,
                                  cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore));

  dim3 dimBlock(8, 8, 1);
  dim3 dimGrid(width / dimBlock.x, height / dimBlock.y, 1);

  cudaSurfaceObject_t outputSurface;
  cudaResourceDesc surfRes;
  memset(&surfRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
  surfRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
  surfRes.res.array.array = cuArray;

  checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&outputSurface, &surfRes));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dData, hData, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  surfaceWriteKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dData, width, height,
                                            outputSurface);
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(dData, 0, size));
  cudaTextureObject_t tex;
  cudaResourceDesc texRes;
  memset(&texRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));

  texRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
  texRes.res.array.array = cuArray;

  cudaTextureDesc texDescr;
  memset(&texDescr, 0, sizeof(cudaTextureDesc));

  texDescr.normalizedCoords = false;
  texDescr.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
  texDescr.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
  texDescr.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
  texDescr.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;

  checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateTextureObject(&tex, &texRes, &texDescr, NULL));

  texReadKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock, 0>>>(dData, width, height, tex);


  // Allocate mem for the result on host side
  mt *hOData = (mt *)malloc(size);
  // copy result from device to host
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(hOData, dData, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  // check
  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      ushort4 val = hOData[row*width+col];
      if (val.x != __half_as_ushort(__float2half(row)))  {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << row << "," << col << std::endl; return 0;}
      if (val.y != __half_as_ushort(__float2half(1.0f))) {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << row << "," << col << std::endl; return 0;}
      if (val.z != __half_as_ushort(__float2half(col)))  {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << row << "," << col << std::endl; return 0;}
      if (val.w != __half_as_ushort(__float2half(2.0f))) {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << row << "," << col << std::endl; return 0;}
      }
  std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;

  checkCudaErrors(cudaDestroySurfaceObject(outputSurface));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaDestroyTextureObject(tex));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(dData));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeArray(cuArray));
}
# nvcc -o t65 t65.cu
# compute-sanitizer ./t65
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
CUDA device [NVIDIA L4] has 58 Multi-Processors, SM 8.9
Success
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
# cat t65f.cu

/*
 * demonstrate "half4" texture/surface using float4 texture fetch
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cuda_fp16.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#define checkCudaErrors(x) {cudaError_t err=x; if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cout << "CUDA Error at line: " << __LINE__ << " " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;}
using mt = ushort4;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Kernels
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Write to a cuArray (texture data source) using surface writes
//! @param gIData input data in global memory
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
__global__ void surfaceWriteKernel(mt *gIData, int width, int height,
                                   cudaSurfaceObject_t outputSurface) {
  // calculate surface coordinates
  unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  // read from global memory and write to cuarray (via surface reference)
  surf2Dwrite(gIData[y * width + x], outputSurface, x * sizeof(mt), y);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! read data using texture lookups
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
__global__ void texReadKernel(int width, int height,
                                cudaTextureObject_t tex) {
  unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  float u = x;
  float v = y;

  // read from texture and write to global memory
  float4 val = tex2D<float4>(tex, u, v);
  if (val.x != v)    printf("mismatchx at %d,%d, was: %f, should be: %f\n", x,y,val.x, v);
  if (val.y != 1.0f) printf("mismatchy at %d,%d, was: %f, should be: %f\n", x,y,val.y, 1.0f);
  if (val.z != u)    printf("mismatchz at %d,%d, was: %f, should be: %f\n", x,y,val.z, u);
  if (val.w != 2.0f) printf("mismatchw at %d,%d, was: %f, should be: %f\n", x,y,val.w, 2.0f);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  // Get number of SMs on this GPU
  cudaDeviceProp deviceProps;
  const int devID = 0;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProps, devID));
  std::cout << "CUDA device [" << deviceProps.name << "] has " << deviceProps.multiProcessorCount << " Multi-Processors, SM " << deviceProps.major << "." << deviceProps.minor << std::endl;

  // create data
  unsigned int width = 256, height=256;
  mt *hData = (mt *)malloc(width*height*sizeof(mt));

  unsigned int size = width * height * sizeof(mt);
  // populate
  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      unsigned short x = __half_as_ushort(__float2half(row));
      unsigned short y = __half_as_ushort(__float2half(1.0f));
      unsigned short z = __half_as_ushort(__float2half(col));
      unsigned short w = __half_as_ushort(__float2half(2.0f));
      ushort4 val = {x, y, z, w};
      hData[row*width+col] = val;}

  // Allocate device memory for result
  mt *dData = NULL;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dData, size));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dData, hData, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  // Allocate array and copy image data
  cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDescHalf4();
  cudaArray *cuArray;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocArray(&cuArray, &channelDesc, width, height,
                                  cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore));

  dim3 dimBlock(8, 8, 1);
  dim3 dimGrid(width / dimBlock.x, height / dimBlock.y, 1);

  cudaSurfaceObject_t outputSurface;
  cudaResourceDesc surfRes;
  memset(&surfRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
  surfRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
  surfRes.res.array.array = cuArray;

  checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&outputSurface, &surfRes));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dData, hData, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  surfaceWriteKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dData, width, height,
                                            outputSurface);
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(dData, 0, size));
  cudaTextureObject_t tex;
  cudaResourceDesc texRes;
  memset(&texRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));

  texRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
  texRes.res.array.array = cuArray;

  cudaTextureDesc texDescr;
  memset(&texDescr, 0, sizeof(cudaTextureDesc));

  texDescr.normalizedCoords = false;
  texDescr.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
  texDescr.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
  texDescr.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
  texDescr.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;

  checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateTextureObject(&tex, &texRes, &texDescr, NULL));

  texReadKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock, 0>>>(width, height, tex);

  checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

  checkCudaErrors(cudaDestroySurfaceObject(outputSurface));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaDestroyTextureObject(tex));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(dData));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeArray(cuArray));
}
# nvcc -o t65f t65f.cu
# compute-sanitizer ./t65f
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
CUDA device [NVIDIA L4] has 58 Multi-Processors, SM 8.9
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
#
```